# Can I use Ubuntu on this desktop (for gaming)?

Tags: 12.04, nvidia, wine, performance, steam

This is my first post. I know there are a lot of VERY similar questions like this, but no one has my PC specs or i didn't found one with them.

Well, here is the story. Since 2010 i have been using ubuntu in my netbook, which makes it 10 times faster. So, i tried to test the new ubuntu 12.04 in my desktop which i use for games (In Steam) and it went really really well, i was amazed over the speed of programs, boot and everything. But, here is the problem. As you read before, i use this deskto for gaming. I know Native Steam is coming eventually for linux, but i'm very impacient.

Do you think I could play smoothly Source games along with steam in this computer, running Wine and/or PlayOnLinux?

PC Specs:

```
Intel Dual Core E5300 @ 2.60 GHz (64 Bits)
Gygabite NVidia Geforce 9800 GT 1 GB
4 GB Ram DDR2
500 GB Seagate HardDrive (Unknown model)
```

Answer (score 2):

> Do you think I could play smoothly Source games along with steam in this computer, running Wine and/or PlayOnLinux?

Yes, I believe it will be a smooth experience.

I have a desktop here with a lesser processor and that plays games over Play On Linux perfectly. Baldur's Gate, Neverwinter Nights, Planescape Torment are not a problem.

Comment: Great :D Now, it isn't a problem, but i play source games at maximum config. Do you think it'll be possible in this case?

Comment: That you will need to find out yourself. I do not play on max config alot (notebook on battery ;) )

Comment: Ok. I did a 60gb partition to test a bit and by far Steam runs with no problems. As soon my games folder gets to this partition i'll test it. Thanks for the help!